# Best way to sum up and divide time

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

read_file = pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx')
read_file['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(read_file['Duration'])
hours = read_file['Duration'].dt.time

uren_lijst = []

for uren in hours:
    uren_lijst.append(uren)
```

This scrip returns a script with datetime.time objects. Modulo does not work for time. What's the best way to work around this?

This is what I want to do: if time is between 8:00 and 8:15, I want to sum up 8 to the total. If time is between 8:15 and 9:00, I want to sum up the time minus 00:15 (for example, 8:30 would sum up 8:15). Everything under 8:00 or above 9:00 has to be sum up to the total completely.

I tried calculating back to seconds and I also tried doing it as strings but that didn't seem to work.

Input is a xlsx file with the data shown beneath.
Current output:

```
['0:00', '8:13', '8:15', '6:42', '0:00', '8:12', '8:12', '8:16', '6:27', '8:20', '6:59', '0:00', '8:27', '8:22', '9:13', '8:26', '8:07', '6:28', '0:00', '8:17', '8:58', '8:10', '8:16', '7:33', '5:43', '0:00', '8:29', '6:54', '7:55', '8:10', '8:10', nan]
```

Edit:

I may have been a little unclear, I apologize. The input is a list of hours and minutes. I have converted it and displayed it as a list (as above).

It's a kind of rounding up with certain conditions.

Every eighth hour should be rounded up to eight to a maximum of fifteen minutes (8:15). (Example: 8:13 becomes 8:00) From 8:15 to 9:00 hours a quarter of an hour must be counted down. (Example: 8:32 becomes 8:17). Everything above 9 and below 8 remains as it is. (Example: 7:30 remains 7:30 and 09:01 remains 09:01). The total of these hours must be added up.

I hope it's clearer this way.

Comment: Please share sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please don't provide image links or images. Paste input and output as code in question itself. Also, your link does not work.

Comment: Sure, i'm sorry.

Comment: Can you add lists of input and output which include examples for all your cases?

Comment: By sum up would you possibly mean rounding ?

Comment: It's a way of rounding based on certain conditions, indeed. I have tried to make it a bit clearer in the head post.

Comment: Your rounding rules are ... super weird. You're going to need to write a function for that. Then just sum normally on the outputs of that function. I would suggest reduce, but that's for python collections -- pandas probably has its own things for working with a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so I did it myself on a rather (probably noob) way, but hey it did the trick. So I first calculated the seconds out of them minutes and hours:

```
def seconden_convert(t):
h, m = [int(i) for i in t.split(':')]
return 3600*h + 60*m
```

After that, I added them to a new list with only seconds:

```
for uren in uren_lijst:
uren_lijst_correct.append(seconden_convert(uren))
```

Then, I created a for loop with the seconds and filtered them the way I needed to:

```
uren_lijst_gefilterd = []

for seconden in uren_lijst_correct:
    if seconden <= 28800 and seconden >= 100:
        uren_lijst_gefilterd.append(seconden)
    elif seconden >= 28801 and seconden <= 29700:
        uren_lijst_gefilterd.append(29700)
    elif seconden >=29701 and seconden <= 32399:
        uren_lijst_gefilterd.append(seconden-900)
    elif seconden >= 32400:
        uren_lijst_gefilterd.append(seconden)
```

Finally I calculated it back to hours and minutes:

```
def uren_convert(seconds): 
min, sec = divmod(seconds, 60) 
hour, min = divmod(min, 60) 
return "%d:%02d" % (hour, min)
```

This is probably a very cumbersome way, but it works and I've learned a lot from it.